# MFC SDI rich edit 2.0 control bolding words

Tags: c++, mfc, format, bold, sdi

How would i go about formatting text in a rich edit 2.0 control? As of right now i just have a simple little MFC program with a single view and just one rich edit 2.0 control. It's currently empty but i want to insert some text into it.

The control itself is labeled as StringToChange2 and the member within my class is m_StringToChange2.

```
    TCHAR INIValue2[256] = _T("Here is some random text!");
    SetDlgItemText(StringToChange2, INIValue2);
```

So as it stands now, when i run my program it inserts the text into my control. How can i make a word bold from the whole string?

For example i just want it to say : "Here is **some** random text!"
As it stands now, i can make the whole control bold but I don't want the whole thing to be bold, just a word.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340367/mfc-richedit2-formatting) has a very similar question to what I am asking but there is 2 things wrong with it. First, almost all the comments tell him to use a HTML control which i don't want to turn to yet. Second, the one person who did respond to him has such a long snippet of code i don't understand what's happening. The very last answer recommends he use word pad since it uses RTF?

I tried to insert RTF code into my INIValue2 but it won't take it. Unless I'm using it wrong, which could highly be the case.

I've been stalking MSDN and reading the functions, but my level of expertise with MFC and richedit control is very limited. If someone could post a small example of this, it doesn't even have to relate to my question , but something i could use as a base for.

Edit1: It's not that my INIValue2 doesn't take it, it's that when it appears on my single view - it shows everything - including all the RTF code and header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format the text using [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. In MFC, you can use `CRichEditCtrl::SetSelectionCharFormat`

First, declare `CRichEditCtrl` member data in your dialog or window class

```
CRichEditCtrl m_richedit;
```

In `OnInitDialog` put

```
m_richedit.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_RICHEDIT21, this);
```

Apply the [`CHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follows:

```
CHARFORMAT cf = { sizeof(cf) };
cf.dwEffects = CFM_BOLD;
cf.dwMask = CFM_BOLD;
m_richedit.SetSel(0,2);
m_richedit.SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);
```

You can use helper functions to make this easier. For example see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13656120/4603670)

---

To assign RTF text directly, you must use [`EM_STREAMIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For some reason MFC has no function for this, so you have to write your own function

```
DWORD __stdcall callback_rtf_settext(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    CString *psBuffer = (CString*)dwCookie;
    if (cb > psBuffer->GetLength()) 
        cb = psBuffer->GetLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < cb; i++) 
        *(pbBuff + i) = (BYTE)psBuffer->GetAt(i);
    *pcb = cb;
    *psBuffer = psBuffer->Mid(cb);
    return 0;
}

bool setrtf(CRichEditCtrl &edit, const CString &s)
{
    EDITSTREAM es;
    edit.SetSel(0, -1);
    edit.Clear();
    memset(&es, 0, sizeof(es));
    es.dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR)&s;
    es.pfnCallback = callback_rtf_settext;
    edit.StreamIn(SF_RTF, es);
    return es.dwError == 0;
}
```

usage:

```
setrf(m_richedit, L"\\rtf data...");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The first option worked for me. I have yet to try to create a RTF function like you explained, but the first option is working just fine. Now using the first method, is there anyway to select a particular word? For example, i won't always know how long a string is and it could say "blah blah blah blah blah important blah blah" and i want to bold important in this case. Would i have to implement a parse function?